# How to display search results in search.php

Tags: search

I am trying to display search results in search.php , but no results showing. it just show this
 search results for: then the keyword I put in the search box only nothing more. so the actual results for the keyword not showing from the posts.

I have two files. here are

search.php

```
<?php get_header();  ?>

     <h5><b>SEARCH RESULTS</b></h5>
     <h3 class="mt-30 mb-15">SEARCH RESULTS FOR YOUR KEYWORD</h3>



<h1><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s'), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>


<?php get_footer();  ?>
```

and searchform.php

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <label for="search">Search in <?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
</form>
```

so what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

[`get_search_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_query/) returns only the string that the user searched for. To display the search results, you'll need to do some more work.

The search results will be in `$wp_query`, and you can manipulate it using The Loop (like any other page).

The following code is adapted from WordPress's own [Twenty Twenty theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwenty/)'s `index.php` file, and can be adapted for your theme's `search.php` file.

```
if ( is_search() ) {
        global $wp_query;

        $archive_title = sprintf(
                '%1$s %2$s',
                '<span class="color-accent">' . __( 'Search:', 'twentytwenty' ) . '</span>',
                '&ldquo;' . get_search_query() . '&rdquo;'
        );

        if ( $wp_query->found_posts ) {
                $archive_subtitle = sprintf(
                        /* translators: %s: Number of search results. */
                        _n(
                                'We found %s result for your search.',
                                'We found %s results for your search.',
                                $wp_query->found_posts,
                                'twentytwenty'
                        ),
                        number_format_i18n( $wp_query->found_posts )
                );
        } else {
                $archive_subtitle = __( 'We could not find any results for your search. You can give it another try through the search form below.', 'twentytwenty' );
        }
}

if ( have_posts() ) {

        $i = 0;

        while ( have_posts() ) {
                $i++;
                if ( $i > 1 ) {
                        echo '<hr class="post-separator styled-separator is-style-wide section-inner" aria-hidden="true" />';
                }
                the_post();

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

        }
    }
```